# Hypothesis testing problem: what is p-value here?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, p-value

The problem reads as follows:

> Suppose there are $n$ boxes with $k$ coins in each. The authorities suspect that there is one fake coin in each box. To check it, they randomly select one coin from each box and test it. Suppose that $r$ coins were found to be fake during the test. Is the hypothesis true at significance level $\alpha$? Suppose $k=100, n=10, r=1, \alpha=0.01$.

Okay, so it seems that the null hypothesis here is the presence of a fake coin (what is the alternative here, by the way?)

As far as I understand, in order to do hypothesis testing, we need to choose the test statistic and the way we calculate the p-value. It seems reasonable to me to choose the number of fake coins $r$ as test statistic and calculate the p-value as
$$
p(t)=P(r\leq{t}|H_0).
$$

My question is: is my problem interpretation and formulation correct? If so, this leads to suspicious numerical results and thus I suspect some kind of mistake here.

Comment: "true at significance level α" is a very unfortunate wording (since it doesn't make any sense). But your interpretation looks right.  What is suspicious about your numerical results?

Comment: @conjugateprior This is absolutely correct because, AFAIK, you can reject the null hypothesis at a given significance level but not accept it. However, that's how the problem is formulated. As for the numerical results, it is easy to calculate that the probability of even not finding a single fake coin is $P(r\leq{0}|H_0)=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{k-1}{k}=\left(\frac{99}{100}\right)^{10} \approxeq 0.9$, so there is no point in even performing the test since the null won't be rejected anyway.

Comment: Or perhaps you just performed the test, and the next task is to explain it in hypothesis testing terms.

Comment: @conjugateprior Do you mean that this kind of result may be what the exercise was made for? That may be the case, but I'm still not completely sure that this is the case so I'm not closing the question yet...Thank you!

Comment: For the p-value you want the probability of seeing all the $t$s that are at least as large as $r$, i.e. a sum over the probabilities of seeing t=1 through t=10. It just so happens that that is 1 minus what you calculated, because there is only one possible t value below r. But that won't usually be the case.

Comment: On an earlier question: the alternative hypothesis is not specified here, because the textbook is thinking in Fisherian rather than Neyman/Pearson mode. p values don't need to know about alternatives because they are explicitly constructed under the assumption that the null is true.  Concepts like power, on the other hand, do require thinking of alternatives.

Comment: @conjugateprior Can you explain why the p-value should be $P(r\geq{t}|H_0)$ instead of $P(r\leq{t}|H_0)$? Doesn't this mean that the larger the $r$, the lower the p-value and the larger the chance to reject the hypothesis?

Comment: I wonder how we are intended to interpret "one fake coin in each box." Does this mean *exactly* one per box or *at least one* per box? And what exactly does it mean for a "hypothesis test to be true"? As far as I know, the test itself cannot have either a logical value or a probability.  Its *outcome* might have a p-value associated with it, but even that is not a logical value. Typically, we would expect such a question to ask our opinion about the *null hypothesis*, not about the test!

Comment: To clarify, the p value should be $P(t \geq r; H_0)$ where $t$ ranges over all the values the statistic *could* have taken under H_0 and $r$ is the value it *did* take in the experiment.

Comment: @whuber it is a fairly badly written problem; I had to read it a few times to see what the author was trying to get at.

Comment: @conjugate If we take the "at least" meaning, then no sufficiently large number $r$ can be evidence against the null, *so only the smallest values of $r$ can be in the critical region.* If we take the "exact" meaning, then *both* very large and very small values of $r$ would be in the critical region.  In neither case does this correspond to your critical region. What, then, is your interpretation of the question that causes you to construct a critical region in this way?

Comment: I had assumed that the question was: can one reject (one-tail implicit) that p=1/k when t is binomially distributed over n trials. and we observe r=1.

Comment: @conjugateprior I agree that the test should be one-tailed but it seems more reasonable to consider the left - tailed test, not the right-tailed (because of the reasons explained by whuber).

Comment: @whuber If what I wrote in the OP is correct, then it doesn't even matter if we adopt the "at least" or "exact" interpretation: the suggested numerical values would never allow us to reject the null at the given significance level (see my second comment).

Comment: [shrugs] my Scalia-sense (for interpreting imprecisely stated original intentions) was never particularly well-developed. That's just what I made of it.  (Unless I am much mistaken, there is nearly no power against a p<1/k alternative here with k so big relative to n)

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of completeness: I found out that my understanding was correct and I was overthinking the problem.

That's what happens when the statements are ambiguous, though.